# gitolite run hook on 'wild' repository creation

Tags: git, gitolite, cgit

I need to run a script that will generate the projects.list file when a new repository is created by one the members of my team.

We develop firmware that branch off from a 'master', but the branches will never be merged back into master. Since there will never be a merge back I decided to make repositories for every distinct version of firmware. I have developed a bash script that will create the projects.list file for me.

```
find repositories/ -iname "*.git" -type d | grep --invert-match "gitolite-admin" | sed 's/repositories\///g' > /srv/git/projects.list
```

Now I am having trouble creating the hook to call that script.

I have tried getting gitolite to generate the file for me but have had no luck with it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**Answer**

In config/gitolite.conf I made the repo def look like this:

```
repo    Firmware/[a-zA-Z0-9].*/[a-zA-Z0-9].*
        C       =   @all
        RW+     =   @all
        R = gitweb
        config gitweb.owner = Repo Manager
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [Gitolite "interfacing with external tools"](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/external.html),

> The list of gitweb-readable repos is written to a file whose name is given by the `rc` file variable `GITWEB_PROJECTS_LIST`.
>   The default value of this variable, if it is not specified or empty, is `$HOME/projects.list`.

So unless you make your repo readable by the special user `gitweb`, Gitolite won't generate/complete the `$HOME/projects.list` for you.

Comment: Thanks! I completely missed that line!